# Implementing a generic List getter with type determined from inner child object?

Tags: c#, generics

For context, I'm creating a wrapper class for Navision web services.

These have the following structure:

```
class JobList_Service :  SoapHttpClientProtocol
{
        public Job[] ReadMultiple()
        {
             ...
        }
}
```

I'd like to do something like the following:

```
var jobWS = new NavService<JobList_Service>();
jobWS.GetAll<Job>();
```

I'm struggling with generics, I somehow need to declare a second type as it's taking the JobList_Service as a type, therefore returning a list of JobList_Service, which is not what I want.

Here's my implementation so far:

```
public class NavService<T> where T :  SoapHttpClientProtocol, new()
{
    private T serviceInstance {get; set;}

    public NavService() 
    {
        serviceInstance = new T();
        ADSecurity.AuthenticateService_CurrentUser(serviceInstance);
    }


    public List<T> GetAll() 
    {
        try
        {
            MethodInfo method = serviceInstance.GetType().GetMethod("ReadMultiple");

            ParameterInfo[] paramTypes = method.GetParameters(); //We know that ReadMultiple takes three arguments, we will make that assumption here.
            var filter = Activator.CreateInstance(paramTypes[0].ParameterType, 0);
            object[] parameters = { filter, "", new Int32() };

            var ret =  (List<T>)/*Problem with this cast, obviously*/ method.Invoke(serviceInstance, parameters) ;
            return ret;


        } catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }

}
```

*EDIT: If anyone can suggest a better title, feel free, I don't know the correct terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* solve this with two type parameters - one for the service type and one for the response type:

```
public class NavService<T, TResponse>
{
    ...

    public List<TResponse> GetAll()
    {

    }
}
```

But, to be honest, it looks like your generic type shouldn't have anything to do with `JobList_Service` at all (since all you're doing with it is instantiating the service) and that you should be implementing an interface and using that as a dependency of `NavService`.

Note: I'm making the assumption here that you have multiple "list services" which each return different types. You didn't mention this in your question but it's the only reason I can think of for needing a generic `GetAll` method.

Start by making a generic "list service" interface that you can implement for different concrete types:

```
public interface IListService<T>
{
    T[] ReadMultiple();
}

public class JobList_Service : IListService<Job>, SoapHttpClientProtocol
{
    public Job[] ReadMultiple()
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

Then pass this into the `NavService` constructor:

```
public class NavService<T>
{
    private IJobListService<T> _serviceInstance;

    public NavService(IJobListService<T> serviceInstance) 
    {
        _serviceInstance = serviceInstance;

        /* authenticate the service outside of this scope (i.e. before
         * it is passed to this ctor). This breaks encapsulation.
         * ADSecurity.AuthenticateService_CurrentUser(serviceInstance); */
    }

    public List<T> GetAll() { }
}
```

This enforces better encapsulation and should also prevent you from having to do all of that unpleasant reflection (you'll have to do some extra legwork on that front yourself as I don't know all of the details of the concrete types) and allow you to just *call methods*.

Edit: Since your comment points out that your services are generated, I'd wrap each of your services in an adapter that you can apply the interfaces to:

```
public class JobListService : IListService<Job>
{
    // Your generated service
    private readonly JobList_Service _service;

    ... // set up service in ctor or wherever

    public Job[] ReadMultiple()
    {
        return _service.ReadMultiple();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, but JobList_Service is auto-generated code, wouldn't I need to add the interface to it's declaration each time I generate it?

Comment: That I didn't realise - in that case, instead of directly applying the interface, I'd just write some small adapters that mirror the method signatures but implement the interface, which back onto the original services.

Comment: Looks like I need to do some research on how to do that, a bit new to generics.

Comment: The interface part is amazing by the way, very clean implementation!

Comment: @David Extended my answer to demonstrate my last comment :)

Comment: Haha I was hoping for a way to map them by reflection somehow, first thing I googled was "Force class to implement interface c#". I guess I'm just too lazy and need to create wrapper classes :) Thank you so much!

Comment: You probably could do that but honestly in this case (unless you have hundreds of these things) it is probably going to be neater just to have a wrapper for each one - it's worth having anyway as it gives you a good clean separation between your code and the service client  code.

Comment: @David if the code generator that produces your service proxy classes uses partial classes, you could add the interface to the class signature in another file.